# WinForms convert from float to string, Input string was not in correct format

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, clr

I am trying to convert a float value to string to display in text box.
But when I assign the value to textbox I get the exception "Input String was not in correct format".

I tried to display this string in a messagebox and it shows. but the assignment to textbox text fails

```
property float Distance
        {
            float get(){return float::Parse(txtDist->Text);}
            void set(float value)
                {
                    String^ str =  String::Format("{0:0.00}",value);
MessageBox::Show(str);//success

                txtDist->Text = str;//Exception
            }


    }
```

Comment: this exception usually occurs while parsing, not when assigning a value to a text box like you say. unless you have some validation in place for that text box, which doesn't recognize the value and throws that exception. is this the case?

Comment: I had a TextChanged event on the textbox and hence was getting the exception.

Comment: so then you fixed the problem?

Comment: Yes, I removed the textchanged event and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please format the text property of your text box. I m writing a sample code in C# Format. You can convert it to your desirable format.

```
textBox1.Text = string.Format("0:0.00", someNumber);
```

I think below should work in your case:

```
 txtDist->Text = String::Format("{0:0.00}",value);
```